# String search multiple values in one cell

Tags: excel, string, search, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet containing a list of strings in one column. The list of strings is made up of several numbers from varying lengths, separated by “/” and “;”  The first entry of the string is a code id (which always has a length of 3)(red in example) followed by an “/” then an amount (which varies in length)(green in example) followed by an “;” if the string continues.
Is there a way to isolate every amount in the string, is this possible with only using built in Excel functions (no VBA)

Examples:

```
151/802;259/22;283/93                       ---> 802 22 93
251/489;166/11;280/12;018/50;274/27;283/93  ---> 489 11 12 50 27 93
```

[image]

Up until now I’ve tried

Dutch Version:

`=DEEL(E2;(VIND.SPEC("/";E2)*1)+1;(VIND.ALLES(";";E2;1)-(VIND.ALLES("/";E2;1)+1)))`

Or in English:

`=MID(E2;(SEARCH(“/”;E2)*1)+1;(FIND(“;”;E2;1)-(FIND(“/”;E2;1)+1)))`

But this only gives me the first entry and I don’t know how loop it for the complete string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Excel O365:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]"))
```

With Older version's (but at least 2013), formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]"),COLUMN(A1))
```

Drag right in case you are using this version.

---

If your goal was to just isolate these amounts to sum them:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]"))
```

[image]

---

If you are interested in what `FILTERXML()` can do for you, you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) an interesting read.

Comment: Very much appreciated! I will definitely look into it, do you know any further sources for more information about it?

Comment: There is more information and links right there for you to study. If the answer helped don't forget to accept it too @Den8

Comment: I’ve bookmarked your link already and I’ll definitely use it more often from now on. I have one more question, if I wanted to use another formula on every specific output, (for example: if the output is >100, then multiply by 1.02.), how could I best do that? Is this possible with XPATH 1.0? @JvdV

Comment: You'd need another question where you explain this in more detail with your own attempt @Den8. But from what you mentioned, yes that's possible!

Comment: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698203/excel-add-an-excel-formula-within-filterxml) I've made another question with more details. Thank you for your help! @JvdV