# Excel - Add an excel formula within FilterXML

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet containing a list of strings in one column. The list of strings is made up of several numbers from varying lengths, separated by “/” and “;” The first entry of the string is a code id (which always has a length of 3)(red in example) followed by an “/” then an amount (which varies in length)(green in example) followed by an “;” if the string continues.

With the help of a member, I can now isolate the green number with the following formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A4);"";TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A4;"/";";");";";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")))
```

However, I still need an other formula that multiplies the green number with a variable, if a condintion is met.

Example function:

```
=IFS(B2<=10;B2*1,25;B2<=20;B2*1,18;B2<=100;B2*1,05;B2<=250;B2*1,01;B2>250;B2)
```

[image]

**Is there a way to combine both these functions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very nice way of dealing with this is assigning the full array to a name, let's say a variable, through `LET()`. So your formula in `B2` would become:

```
=IF(A2<>"",LET(MNT,TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")),IFS(MNT<=10,MNT*1.25,MNT<=20,MNT*1.18,MNT<=100,MNT*1.05,MNT<=250,MNT*1.01,MNT>250,MNT)),"")
```

[image]

It, however, does require Excel O365. But since you are transposing the array it appears you do have that.

Comment: Greatly appreciated! Where did you learn most of this, if I may ask?

Comment: @Den8, you'r welcome. I learned most by just playing around with formulas for years out of interest.