# Add ifs function with multiple true filterxml variables

Tags: arrays, excel, xml, string, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet containing a list of strings in one column. The list of strings is made up of several numbers from varying lengths, separated by “/” and “;” The first entry of the string is a code id (which always has a length of 3) followed by an “/” then an amount (which varies in length) followed by an “;” if the string continues. (Example below text)

I can isolate the amounts with this function:

```
TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]"))
```

However, I still need the ifs function to multiply the variables from the string, so I assigned set variables for the array:

```
LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0 and .<=10]"))
LET(Y,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0 and .>10 and .<=20]"))
LET(Z,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0 and .>20]"))
```

Then I made the IFS function for which it should work (this is just an example the actual IFS function is way longer):

```
IFS(AND(A2=2,X<=10),X*1.09,AND(A2=2,Y>10,Y<=20),Y*1.14,AND(A2=2,Z>20),Z*1.21)
```

I tried to put these together and I came up with this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B30,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0 and .<=10]"),Y,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B30,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0 and .>10 and .<=20]"),Z,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B30,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0 and .>20]"),IFS(AND(A30=2,X<=10),X*1.09,AND(A30=2,Y>10,Y<=20),Y*1.14,AND(A30=2,Z<=20),Z*1.21)))
```

However, this only returns the variables X, which are smaller or equal to ten.

Is there a way to make this work for all variables X,Y and Z?

What the formula returns

```
018/2;274/21;218/15 -> 2*1.09
```

What it needs to return

```
018/2;274/21;218/15 -> 2*1.09 21*1.21 15*1.14
```

Edit:
The A2 in my previous mentioned formula is also a variable, which varies between 1 and 28, according to this variable the multiplier changes as can be seen by the following example:
[image]

Comment: I fail to see why this is different to your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64698688/9758194) question? I've showed you there how to implement `IFS()` and `LET()` correctly leading to the right results.

Comment: To add to the above, the formula I have given you works flawless on the example you have given here with the only adjustment being made to the `IFS`, e.g.: `=IF(A2<>"",LET(MNT,TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")),IFS(MNT<=10,MNT*1.09,MNT<=20,MNT*1.14,MNT>20,MNT*1.21)),"")`. All those nested X,Y,Z variables and `AND()` functions is overcomplicating the matter I'm afraid.

Comment: I think the problem is not with your function rather with an extra variable needed: ""=IF(B2<>"";LET(MNT;TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2;"/";";");";";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s[position() mod 2 = 0]"));X;A2;IFS(AND(X=2;MNT<=10);MNT*1.09;AND(X=2;MNT<=20);MNT*1.14;AND(X=2;MNT>20);MNT*1.21));"")""

Comment: Because (example), the variable MNT has to be smaller or equal to ten and A2 is another variable and that combination yields those numbers

Comment: You don't need that, `IFS()` will iterate over the arguments in order. Therefor you don't need the `AND()` to check if a value is between two values at all. And if I happen to not really understand you then maybe add better sample data with what is in `A2` and what is your expected outcome and in which cells. The formula I added in my previous comment gets you the results you want.

Comment: I indeed forgot to mention the reason for the A2 variable, I've edited it and hopefully everything is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the following would work for your needs (after our long chat):

```
=IF(A2<>"",LET(MNT,TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")),MUL,INDEX({1.65\1.35\0.14,1.85\1.47\0.24,2.05\2.48\0.5},MATCH(A2,{1,2,4,6,8,10,12,16,20,24,28},0),0),IFS(MNT<=10,MNT*INDEX(MUL,1),MNT<=20,MNT*INDEX(MUL,2),MNT>20,MNT*INDEX(MUL,3)+35)),"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B30,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]"),
y,{0,1.09;10,1.14;20,1.21},
x *INDEX(y,MATCH(x,INDEX(y,0,1)),2))
```

or

```
=TRANSPOSE(LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B30,"/",";"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]"),
y,{0,1.09;10,1.14;20,1.21},
x *INDEX(y,MATCH(x,INDEX(y,0,1)),2)))
```

[image]

If you also need to check that `A2=2`, do something like:

```
=if(a2=2,the_long_formula)))
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated for your answer! This indeed works for a part of my problem. The other part of the problem that I’m facing is that the A2 is not constant, but a variable. I’ve edited my question, hopefully that makes it clearer.

Comment: @Den8 That is a simple adjustment.  The array constant in the formula is a simple two-column lookup table with the values in column 1, and the multiplier in column 2.  You can easily extend that or, more simply, set up the table externally and refer to it by name.  You then use the value in A2 to index into the desired multiplier column.  In general, when you find yourself dealing with many IF's, think about using a lookup table instead.  Is it only the multiplier that changes?  Or do the points at which you split the values change also?  The solution would be different in that case.

Comment: This seems to be a viable option for my problem, but in addition to what you've stated, The mulipier is not one-fixed number for the variable "weight". The multiplier is a combination of the ''weight" and the corresponding value [.<=10, .>10 .<=20 en .>20 ], because every weight has 3 different multipliers. @JvdV gave a formula that yields the correct answer. However, your approach might work aswell, would a four-column lookup table work just as well as what you stated previously?

Comment: @Den8 Some kind of table would work well. The design depends on the **specifics** of what the values in A2 represent.